# In the category of schemes, what conditions on a closed monomorphism make it a closed immersion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

If the question can be simplified, we can work on smaller categories, such as the category of varieties or schemes of finite type over a field, etc.

By a closed morphism of schemes I mean it is closed as a continuous map, not a closed immersion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closed immersions are exactly the proper monomorphisms, see Stacks [04KV](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04XV). You'll also find a few other conditions there. Any of the following conditions in addition to being a monomorphism will imply your morphism is a closed immersion:

- proper (i.e. universally closed, separated, finite type)
- universally closed + unramified
- universally closed + locally of finite type

This implies, for instance, that a universally closed monomorphism of varieties (schemes of finite type over a field) is a closed immersion.